# Referencing root when using sub folders in IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I'm referring to the .js and .css files in my application as follows.

```
<!-- CORE JQUERY  -->
<script src="/Content/Templete/assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="/Content/Templete/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

and page redirect as follows.

> href="/Journal/CreateJournal.aspx"

Javascript as follows

```
url: "/Journal/AccountLookUp.aspx/accountFilter",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Application is hosted in IIS in a sub folder and all the references above is broken.

http://mydoin.com - Hosting here works fine.
http://mydoin.com/subApplicationFolder - All the links are broken

Is there any setting in IIS to make this work?

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet? Please share me the solution.